# Where is the information for context menus stored in various OS?

Tags: windows, macos, ubuntu, contextmenu

### Windows

[image]

### Ubuntu and Mac

[image]

Windows was fairly simple (thanks to SO community member `ExpertSystem`for helping me on this). The context menu information is stored in `Registry`

I do not know where the information for context menu is stored for `Ubuntu` and `Mac`.
**Where is this information stored?**

Answer (score 2):

For OSX, an application creates a bundle, which is a special type of folder containing various files and the executable for the application. One of those is Info.plist where a .plist file is an XML file of named value types. You'll need to modify that and register the change with LaunchServices.

The answer is explained in more detail [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/15030/how-can-i-add-a-new-application-to-the-open-with-menu)

Answer (score 1):

**context menue**

Ubuntu (with unity) is using Nautilus as default file manager. other file manager, other location.

information for nautilus is stored here:
~/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts

Further you should google for nautilus actions.

Have a look at:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/21953/how-to-customize-the-context-menu-in-nautilus

**context menue - openwith only**

If you are searching for a simple OpenWith - you just can create a .desktop file - whitch is also selectable in GTK3 Natulis-Versions.